# Save each worksheet as individual document (values only)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save multiple worksheets as individual documents. I have a code but the tricky part is to save values only (excel contains formulas). Each worksheet have different name which becomes the name of separate excel. 
How can I adjust the code? Please help. Thanks!

The code is:

```
Sub Make_New_Books()
Dim w As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    w.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path &     
"\Requests_for_local_suppliers_to_send\" & w.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next w
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: After your `w.Copy` line, you could Select All, Copy, and then PasteSpecial (values only) over the top, before completing the save.

Comment: This would be the VBA for it: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select`, `Selection.Copy`, `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: Thanks Joe! But it will remove formulas from the original document...

Comment: Or not? Will it impact only destination file?

Comment: It should only affect the destination file. When you execute `w.Copy` it create a new worksheet/workbook, which automatically becomes the `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook`. The parent workbook does not regain focus until you close the new copy, and your pasting operation is already complete by then.

Comment: @JoeMalpass: Would you mind rewriting your comment as an answer so we can close the question and refer to it in the future?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly straightforward edit to the existing code. After the `w.Copy` command we are simply going to select "everything" with `UsedRange`, then copy and pastespecial the values only, over the top of the original data.

`.Copy` creates a new worksheet, so the formulas in the parent worksheet remain unaffected by this operation.

```
Sub Make_New_Books()
Dim w As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    w.Copy
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path &     
"\Requests_for_local_suppliers_to_send\" & w.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next w
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```